# Can one change Azure Active Directory B2C SSO Saml Audience Restriction?

Tags: single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, saml, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to SSO using Azure Active Directory B2C to a Service Provider. I am using IDP initiated sign in.

The Service Provider requires the audience to be their own URI (or have no audience restriction at all).

The current SAML assertion contains:

```
<saml:Conditions NotBefore="{DATE}" NotOnOrAfter="{LATER_DATE}">
    <saml:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml:Audience>
            **https://{my-b2c-domain}.onmicrosoft.com/{app-registration-guid}**
        </saml:Audience>
    </saml:AudienceRestriction>
</saml:Conditions>
```

And I want it to be like:

```
<saml:Conditions NotBefore="{DATE}" NotOnOrAfter="{LATER_DATE}">
    <saml:AudienceRestriction>
        <saml:Audience>
            **https://{service-provider-domain}**
        </saml:Audience>
    </saml:AudienceRestriction>
</saml:Conditions>
```

or

```
<saml:Conditions NotBefore="{DATE}" NotOnOrAfter="{LATER_DATE}" />
```

I have tried changing the Item tags in the TechnicalProfile to include things such as

```
<Item Key="Audience">**https://{service-provider-domain}**</Item>
<Item Key="AudienceUri">**https://{service-provider-domain}**</Item>
```

and other changes that have not affected the audience.

I have also tried using ClaimsTransformations but none seem to validate properly.

My question is how can I accomplish this using my custom policies or is this is even possible?